# Metodo each_slice Ruby

Tags: ruby

Buen día,
Estoy desarrollando una metodo en ruby que me indique si un número es colorful, por esta vez solo con numeros de 3 digitos.

```
def colorful?(number)
  # TODO: return true if the number is colorful, false otherwise
  single_number = number.to_s.chars
  array = []
  for i in (0..single_number.size-1)
    single_number.each_slice(i + 1) { |a| array << a }
  end
  array
end

p colorful?(263)
```

Por ahora según avanzo, este método me devuelve `[["2"], ["6"], ["3"], ["2", "6"], ["3"], ["2", "6", "3"]]`

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma para hacer que each_slice(i) me devuelva si o si un array del tamaño que tiene el argumento. Por ahora, cuando llega al each_slice(2) me devuelve un `["2", "6"], ["3"]`, quisiera que me retorne `["2", "6"], ["6", "3"]`.

Existe alguna forma para forzar each_slice para que me devuelva solo arrays del tamaño que le indico?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) en lugar de `each_slice`:

```
"263".chars.each_cons(2).map(&:itself)
#=> [["2", "6"], ["6", "3"]]
```

---

Como mejora a tu código, podrías optar por `each` (o mejor aún, `each_with_object` para evitar la variable `array`) en lugar del `for` (`for` rara vez se ocupa en Ruby):

```
def colorful?(number)
  single_number = number.to_s.chars

  (0...single_number.size).each_with_object([]) do |n, array|
    single_number.each_cons(n + 1) { |a| array << a }
  end
end

colorful?(263)
#=> [["2"], ["6"], ["3"], ["2", "6"], ["6", "3"], ["2", "6", "3"]]
```

---

Otra opción (la mejor a mi gusto) puede ser con `flat_map` y `map`, la cual muestra simplifica más el código:

```
def colorful?(number)
  single_number = number.to_s.chars

  (0...single_number.size).flat_map do |n|
    single_number.each_cons(n + 1).map(&:itself)
  end
end

colorful?(263)
#=> [["2"], ["6"], ["3"], ["2", "6"], ["6", "3"], ["2", "6", "3"]]
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvio tu ayuda